# Weakly mixing diffeomorphism

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

From

> *Halmos, Paul R.*, [**In general a measure preserving transformation is mixing**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969304), Ann. Math. (2) 45, 786-792 (1944). [ZBL0063.01889](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.01889).

the following result is known:  Let $(E,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space which is isomorphic to the unit interval. And let $G=G(E,\mu)$ be the space of all invertible measure preserving transformations on  $(E,\Sigma, \mu)$. Then the subset of $G$ made up of weakly mixing maps is *a dense $G_\delta$ set*.

Can a similar statement be proved if we replace in some way $G$ with the set of measure-preserving $C^1$ diffeomorphisms of the circle, $\mathrm{Diff}^1(\mathbb T)$?

Comment: Are you asking if WM is generic inside $Diff^{1}$? With what topology? the $C^{1}$-topology?

Comment: Homeomorphisms of the circle are never weak mixing.

Comment: @Asaf I don't know which topology is more appropriate to consider

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Why not? And isn't this incompatible with Halmos' result?

Comment: Halmos's result permits discontinuous maps.  Piecewise linear maps with finitely (or infinitely) many discontinuities are allowed, for example.

Comment: Given an orientation-preserving homeomorphism, it has a rotation number $a$. If $a$ is irrational, there is a factor map from $T$ to a rigid rotation by $a$. That precludes weak mixing. If $a$ is rational, any ergodic invariant measure is supported on a periodic orbit so is not weak-mixing. If $T$ is orientation-reversing, then $T^2$ is orientation-preserving, so not weak-mixing.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I see; thanks! So the result would be restricted to $G(\mathbb T)$ only (defined as in the question) instead of $\mathrm{Diff}^1(\mathbb T)$, right?

Comment: Yes. I think this is exactly right.

Comment: The factor map given by the rotation number is topological so does not contradict measure theoretic weak mixing of a measure preserving homeomorphism. The result of Alpern shows that weak mixing is generic in the space of measure preserving homeomorphisms of the circle. See the survey “ Properties generic for Lebesgue space automorphisms are generic for measure-preserving manifold homeomorphisms” of Alpern and Prasad

Comment: "The result of Alpern shows that weak mixing is generic in the space of measure preserving homeomorphisms of the circle": Homeomorphisms (i.e. continuous bijections from the circle to itself) - certainly not (see above). Automorphisms (in the sense of measurable bijections that preserve the measure, but may not be continuous) - probably.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I found indeed that the result seems to hold for homeomorphisms: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01425570 where the paper Katok, A., Stepin, A.: Metric properties of measure preserving homeomorphisms is cited. What's the catch? Is there some hidden assumption that doesn't make it apply to the case of homeomorphisms of the circle?

Comment: @user490373  The dimension ought to be at least $2$ for all the Oxtoby-Ulam, Katok-Stepin, Alpern, Prasad etc. arguments (essentially because of the rotation number obstruction in dimension $1$ as Prof. Quas stated).

Comment: @AlpUzman I see. Does the claim hold if I replace "weakly mixing" with "ergodic"?

Comment: @user490373 The answer is still no: the rotation number is continuous when the homeo group is endowed with the uniform topology; and the homeos with rational rotation number is open and dense. The only ergodic probability measures under such homeos are uniform measures supported on periodic orbits, as such the generic circle homeo is not ergodic w/r/t Haar.

Comment: Further, a theorem of Arnold shows that a similar result holds in the $C^1$ diffeo group. (see Thm.5 on p.266 of his paper "Small Denominators I. Mappings of the circumference onto itself", which is included (in English) in his Collected Works Volume I).

Comment: For the homeo case see e.g. Ghys' survey "Groups acting on the circle" (https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/groupscircle.pdf), Prop.5.12 on p.358. (up to an exercise on periodic points and ergodicity)